# Testing MPMoviePlayerViewController in iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a view that shows a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` modally. When testing it in the iPad simulator it works well on the first try. If I dismiss the video and then show the view again, the player only plays the audio, but not the video.

Is this a simulator quirk or am I doing something wrong? Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* v = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(playbackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:v.moviePlayer];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:v];
    [v release];
}

-(void) playbackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:player];
    [player stop];
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the code to create one view controller in the `viewWillAppear` of another view controller, why not just create the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` directly?  Usually view controllers are created or shown in direct response to some user action.  Other than that there is nothing wrong with the code shown.  I have never had any trouble playing movies in the simulator, but I created the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in didSelectRow or in response to a button click.

Comment: Thanks. I want to show the MPMoviePlayerViewController full-screen after clicking on a tab bar icon, that's why I'm using another view controller.

Comment: I found a view to create the MPMoviePlayerViewController using the tab bar controller delegate. Thanks!